# Reading a column in python cursor prints weird?

Tags: python, python-2.7, pyodbc

I have two rows of data. I am trying to return both rows:

```
 sqlReadtObservationId = 'select ObservationId from [dbo].[tObservationRawDataObservations] where ' \
                                            'ObservationRawDataId = ' + str(ObservationRawDataId)
    for (ObservationId) in read_tObservationId_cursor:
         print  str(ObservationId)
```

above prints `(22641472, )`
i expect it to print `22641472` only

Why this occurs? My other sql queries returns results fine.

Comment: the return value is a tuple. If you want only the value try `print  str(ObservationId[0])`

Comment: You seem to be new to Python; I don’t see it in your tags. You may want to consider learning Python 3 instead. Python 2 will stop being supported at the end of 2019.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't see in your code (perhaps you didnt' paste that part in) that you're fetching the data after executing a sql querie. Like this:

```
sql = 'SELECT* from table where table.id = ' + str(someId)

cursor = cursor.execute(sql)

data = cursor.fetchall()

for row in data:
   print(someID)
```

'fetching' returns a tuple for each row of data. So for example when using `fetchone()` it will only return one tuple that you can than iterate to get to the a column.

When using `fetchall()` or `fetchmany()` it will return a list of tuples.

Comment: Correction: pyodbc does not return a row as a `tuple`; it returns a `pyodbc.Row` object. A `pyodbc.Row` behaves like a `tuple` in many respects, but they are not the same thing.